# Passar banco e tabela como parâmetros para procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso de fazer um *Stored procedure* do seguinte tipo:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DR @bd NVARCHAR(20), @VAL AS INT
AS

SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM @bd where campo =@val 

SELECT campo1, campo2 from #temp
Em que @bd seria a base de dados e a tabela que iria utilizar.
```

Como passar esta indicação para o *Stored procedure*?

Se colocar a BD\tabela de forma manual o SP está a funcionar como pretendo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode criar uma query dinâmica com os parâmetros e executar com `EXEC()`, assim por exemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DR @bd NVARCHAR(20), @VAL AS INT
AS

DECLARE @COMANDO nvarchar(1000)    
SET @COMANDO = 'SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM ' +  @bd + where campo = ' + STR(@val)
EXEC (@COMANDO)

SELECT campo1, campo2 from #temp
```

Assim pode montar toda a query dinamicamente e executar em seguida. Note que, como o parâmetro @val é `INT` precisa converter, porque todo o conteúdo de @COMANDO é `nvarchar`

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo.
já tinha tentado uma abordagem do género, sem sucesso.
Recebo a mensagem:
"
(564 rows affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure dbo.sp_dr, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid object name '#TEMP'.
"

Comment: Aproveitei a sua dica com a seguinte alteração:  dentro do SP criei uma tabela (#TEMP) com a mesma estrutura da original, e no comando utilizei   'INSERT INTO #temp SELECT * FROM ' + @bd + ' WHERE campo  = ' + STR(@val). no final DROP TABLE #temp

Comment: acho que o erro pode ser porque, como é uma tabela temporária, ele tenha sido criada em algum contexto a parte dentro do `exec`, o que faz ela não ficar visível fora do `exec`, por ser temporaria pode por exemplo colocar o `select` também dentro do `exec` e fazer um teste. Outra alterantiva seria criar a tabela como "global temporary", ou seja, com ##TEMP. O ponto negativo é que como é global, pode dar conflito com outro usuário, então precisava gerar um nome único antes de criar e preferencialmente fazer um `drop table` ao final